# Find the coefficient of $x^n$ simply by using binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $x^n $ in the expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x+x^2-x^3}$.

Comment: Do you know the expansion if ${1\over 1-x}$ ?

Comment: This is not a homework-solving site. Try do it yourself and ask here if you get stuck.

Comment: I made the title more descriptive. I still predict the question to be put on hold sooner rather than later. You should at least describe a related example problem you understand. Otherwise we cannot help you learn how to solve this yourself.

Comment: What happens when this is the first problem you've seen like this?

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{1}{1-x+x^2-x^3}=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1-x)}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}+\frac{1} {1-x})$.

Clearly $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots$ and

$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots$

from here $\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}=1+x-x^2-x^3+x^4+x^5\dots$

So $\frac{1}{1-x+x^3-x^3}=1+x+x^4+x^5+x^8+x^9+\dots$

Comment: so the coefficient of $x^n$ is $1$ if $n$ is $0$ or $1\bmod 4$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I really don't see why the many downvotes. If you spot a mistake, write a comment. (+1)