# want to check answer given in my book is correct or not

Tags: taylor-expansion, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

The problem is to find coefficient of $x^n$ using binomial theorem for rational index in the expansion of $$\frac{1}{1-x+x^2-x^3}.$$ 
In my book the answer is given as $$\frac14+\frac{n+1}{2}+\frac{(-1)^n}{4}.$$ I think the answer in book is wrong.

I will be grateful if anyone check and tell this answer is correct or not with explanation. thanks

Comment: Thanks for editing@gt6989b

Comment: Add your answer also .

Comment: Why do you think the book is wrong?

Comment: A copy of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868757/11619) question by the same asker. Do. Not. Reask. EVER! That is a rule we uphold strictly. It often leads to waste of efforts for others, and therefore we think it's rude.

Comment: OK I'm sorry for that .hereafter I won't do like this and I'm new to this site .so I won't know about that.

Comment: Can u tell me how to delete this post,@Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: Because I find a answers which is completely different from book answer ,I tried every thing that I know and arrive at same answer .so I think the answer in book is a error while printing @fleablood

Comment: Well, for the love of jeebus WHAT do you think the correct answer should be?  Sheesh!

Comment: The final equation must be $$1+x+x^4+x^5+x^8+x^9+...$$ so assuming n in terms of m,co efficient of $x^n$ is 1 if n=4m or 4m+1.  Where m$\in$W @fleablood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps somewhat easier:

$$1-x+x^2-x^3=(1-x)(1+x^2)\implies\frac1{1-x+x^2-x^3}=\frac1{(1-x)(1+x^2)}$$

Now simple fractions:

$$\frac1{(1-x)(1+x^2)}=\frac A{1-x}+\frac{Bx+C}{1+x^2}\implies1=A(1+x^2)+(Bx+C)(1-x)$$

Comparing coefficients for different values of $\;x\;$ , say for $\;x=1\;$ and coefficients of different powers of $\;x\;$ , we get:

$$\begin{align*}&x=1: \implies&1=2A\implies \color{red}{A=\frac12}\\{}\\&x^2: \implies&0=A-B\implies \color{red}{B=\frac12}\\{}\\&x:\implies&0=B-C\implies \color{red}{C=\frac12}\end{align*}$$

and we get

$$\frac1{(1-x)(1+x^2)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-x}+\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}\right)=$$

$$=\frac12\left(1+x+x^2+\ldots+1-x^2+x^4-\ldots+x-x^3+x^5-\ldots\right)=$$

$$\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(x^k+(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac k2\right\rfloor}x^k\right)=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac k2\right\rfloor}\right)x^k\implies$$

so the coefficient of $\;x^n\;$ is

$$\frac12\left(1+(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor}\right)$$

observe this coefficient vanishes whenever

$$(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor}=-1\iff \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor\;\;\text{is odd}\iff n=2,3\pmod 4$$

**Another way**: since $\;x^4-1=(x^2-1)(x^2+1)=(x+1)(x^3-x^2+x-1)\;$ , we have

$$\frac1{1-x+x^2-x^3=}=\frac{1+x}{1-x^4}=\left(1+x\right)\left(1+x^4+x^8+\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(x^{4k}+x^{4k+1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1+x\right)x^{4k}$$

Both ways above render the same answer (check this), so I'd say definitely your book is wrong...or else you're looking at the wrong question's answer...or else I am wrong, of course. Twice.

Comment: Hey, you're back! Welcome back!

Comment: I would get the same answer that u give ..thanks for our effort to help me sir

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you. Yes, I've been around a few weeks ago already but not too much participating. Now a little more as it is summer time and most exams (even moed bet) are over. Nice to meet you again.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x+x^2-x^3}
     = \frac{1+x}{1-x^4}
     = \frac{1}{1-x^4} + x \frac{1}{1-x^4}
$$

You can write
$$
\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + \ldots
$$
So can you expand $f(x)$ into series and find the coefficient of $x^n$?

Comment: But ik how to find coefficient sir ,I want to know the answer in book is correct or not

Comment: @SathasivamK people here generally don't like to do your homework for you, please show some effort. $f(x)$ has 2 terms. Can you find the coefficient of $x^n$ in the first term? in the second term? then add them together. Feel free to post answers here, i will be happy to look over your progress

Comment: I'mI'm sorry but it is not my home work,I just try to solve every question in my reference book .its not my home work sir@gt6989b